# How to watch Apple keynote videos from the website

Tags: video, apple

I just noticed that I am unable to watch Apple's keynote videos on Ubuntu 12.10. Neither Firefox nor Google Chrome works. 
I am however, able to view all the advertisement videos for all products on Apple's website. The link to the keynote video is [here](http://www.apple.com/uk/apple-events/october-2012/)
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm willing to say this should be asked on the Apple Stack Exchange site. Apple doesn't want people who don't have Macs to watch it.

Comment: @MarcoCeppi I'm baffled as to why Apple wouldn't want as many people to watch this as possible.  It's probably more a web development issue than a decree from Apple to bar Linux users from watching their streams.  Anyway, it's not hard to get around; see my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Where there is a will, there is a way.  Apple changes links and their website around frequently, but in general, what you have to do is this:  open the page source.  Look for urls or javascripts that seem like they will open the video stream.  They used to have bare urls, but now there is usually some javascript that does the job.  I would look for something with `edgesuite.net` (or `events.apple.com`) in it.  I found `http://events.apple.com.edgesuite.net/1210pibasdfvoihbadsv/event/url.js`

I opened the `js` file and found:

```
/*snowLeopard url*/
var slURL = "http://qthttp.apple.com.edgesuite.net/1210pibasdfvoihbadsv/sl_vod_mvp.m3u8";

/* non-snowLeopard url*/
var nonSlURL = 'http://stream.qtv.apple.com/events/oct/1210pibasdfvoihbadsv/12poibnasfdvpiajbafvpihjbasfvpiubfsv10_350_vod_ref.mov';
```

etc.

I took the Snow Leopard URL and tried opening it in `VLC` (using "open network stream") and it didn't work initially.  So I tried running it via command line, got some `libav` error, googled around a bit, and finally tried:

```
vlc --ffmpeg-threads=1 'http://qthttp.apple.com.edgesuite.net/1210pibasdfvoihbadsv/sl_vod_mvp.m3u8'
```

which worked perfectly.

Comment: excellent. it worked. I would have loved if this could be done in easier way. think about all those who would like to try Ubuntu/Linux for the first time and get put off by the sheer amount of work they would have to do in order to get a keynote speech to play. A clever ploy by Apple.

Answer (score -2):

They cant be actually..

Because, if you click on the videos, below you will see the requirements which clearly indicate the need of an apple device or atleast software(quicktime in case of windows)..

but one workaround is to install wine and install the safari browser on wine...

but that seems like a way too large workaround! rather wait for a week maybe and watch them on youtube then ;)