# How to watch Apple Videos (2014)

Tags: video, apple

I am rather new to Ubuntu (I have Ubuntu 14.04) so sorry if this is a bit amatuerish. So apple's new [live event](http://www.apple.com/live/2014-sept-event/) for unsupported OS's is just a live stream of banners and video updates, but I can't play any of the videos. On chrome I just get a "missing plugin" image, with no prompt to download any software. 
[image]

I tried installing the [restricted-extras-package](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats) but it still won't work, and many of the links for Quicktime go to [this uninformative webpage](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Medibuntu) about how all the plugins were deprecated. I'd rather not hunt and peck for every media source as [this askUbuntu answer suggests](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206824/how-to-watch-apple-keynote-videos-from-the-website), so is there some other way?

EDIT: firefox doesn't seem to work either

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Latest Apple Live Event has been made available exclusively for Safari on OsX, iOS (Recording then added QuickTime for Windows)

No Other Platform/Browser combination is was allowed.

You may better wait for the official video to be uploaded to Apple Youtube Channel to watch it with the best watching experience.

[image: Apple Event Stream Disclaimer]

Comment: oh huh, my webpage says "Live streaming video requires Safari...", so I thought the regular videos would work. bummer

Comment: HYG: http://youtu.be/38IqQpwPe7s